# ASP.NET MVC 3: Change resource file texts in web frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, resources

I'm facing the following situation:

- Complex MVC application with multiple projects
- Should be able to handle multiple languages (not every language is already defined)
- The resource keys will always be available, just the values are
  different per language
- Service layer and web layer needs resources
- Resources are in its own project
  Resources are public, with build action embedded resource and custom tool PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

The game changer:

- The resource texts for each language should be editable in the web frontend and should be on the fly available

And here is the problem. Reading and displaying the contents of each resource in the frontend is no problem.

Reading the localized resource files on behalf of the set CultureInfo:

```
var resourceSet = ResourceFile.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, false);
```

Is it possible to change the resource files anyway? What would be another approach? The database way?

I found [this](http://geeksship.com/LocalTopic/15630ace-5197-45cb-b925-9de9010d4b8f/en-US/A-simple-mvc-example-to-view-and-edit-NET-resource-resx-files.aspx) approach. But it probably won't work within our environment since we have a seperate project for the resources and needs them in multiple projects.

My (simple) thoughts about the database way:

- Every needed string for every ViewModel would be defined in ViewModelBase >:/
- Controller gets the needed strings per View and set locale out of repository and sets them into the ViewModel
- View would access the resources per ViewModel.Key

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer: We stored all the resources in the database and coded a custom resource provider.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change the resource files anyway?

No, not with resource files. You could write a [`custom resource provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) and store them in another storage such as a database for example.

Comment: Is this still the preferred way? (.net 2.0..) Any best practices with custom resource providers with MVC?